# Force clearing cache in IE8

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

Below are the codes have tried for clearing the cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="proxy-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Is the website already published or not? If not, the tags you mentioned will work if the cache has never been used. You could simply clear your own cache and when the users get the 1st version, it will no be cached. If the users already cached the page, my tags should be a better idea.

Please tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```